# Reg using Jasper reports in PHP/MySQL web application installed using XAMPP

Tags: jasper-reports

For our web application using PHP  & MySQL DB we need to generate reports using jasper reports. We are using XAMPP

We have installed Jaspersoft iReport 5.6.0

To connect to DB - I tried the steps as in this ref link http://chathurangat.blogspot.in/2012/03/jasperreports-with-php.html

```
    1) I selected MySQL (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver) - JDBC Driver (as in step No. 6)
    2) Please suggest what I need to give JDBC url for this jdbc:mysql://localhost/DatabaseName
    3) My DB is availabe in MySQL - this can be accessed using phpmyadmin interface
```

Please suggest how can we connect to our MySQL DB

Please suggest whether we need to install anything aditionally

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you login into the jasper reports server, there is a root on you left hand side:

1. Root -> Data Sources.
2. Data sources -> right click. You will be given open options.
3. Choose Add Resource -> Data Source.
4. You will select MYSQL ODBC driver in the drop down box for JDBC Driver:
5. Input all the right fields and then test your connection.